# Power Automate: Run a child flow by GUID

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to call a child flow from a Power Automate flow by it's guid (by using an Expression in the Child Flow dropdown), instead of hardcoding the child flow selection.

However, whenever I try to save the parent flow, I get the following error:

> Request to XRM API failed with error: 'Message: Flow client error returned with status code "BadRequest" and details "{"error":{"code":"ChildFlowIdNotValid","message":"The workflow id '[[expression]]' is not a valid child flow id. The id must be a valid GUID."}}". Code: 0x80060467

I tried various expression, even simple stuff like `@guid()` (which is definitely a valid guid), but to no avail.

It seems like the platform performs a "compile time" check on the value, which makes using any dynamic value impossible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think that Run Child flow action is designed to be more interactive than programmable, unfortunately. **Interacting with the Run Child Flow action calls an API, and the response is used to modify the action definition.** Whatever is the "custom value" expression - it is not evaluated, but instead read as string, and used in a call to retrieve the sample header. That sample is then used to re-format the Run Child Flow action to show the appropriate headers.
Having an undetermined target would mean the call body is not defined, which could be a problem. Interestingly, it does pop a spot for a body when initially trying to look for a hard-coded GUID.

You can see the after-effect of this behavior in how even hardcoded GUIDs get replaced with the flow names once saved/reopened.

As a workaround, I stack Run Child flows in a Switch action checking an expression result. I.e.:

[Switch workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAMQf.png)

Side note - [GUID() in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#guid) (and powerautomate) does not format an arbitrary string as GUID.